# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Name'

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create a basic form using python which has only one field `your_name` in the table `NameForm`. But i am getting the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Name'`. I dont understand where this error comes from. Could anyone help me with it? I am using django 1.11. 
models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class NameForm(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic

from .models import NameForm

class NameView(generic.NameView):
model = NameForm
template_name = 'home/name.html'

def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.NameView.as_view(), name='name'),
]
```

template/home/name.html

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: But your `views.py` has no `Name` class... `get_name` is furthermore not a class-based view.

Comment: ```
class NameView(generic.NameView):
    model = NameForm
    template_name = 'home/name.html'
``` i have added this even then i am getting the same error

Comment: Then your URL should reference `views.NameView`, not `views.Name`. But there's no such thing as `generic.NameView` to inherit from anyway.

Comment: i have edited the code. I changed the url.. even then i have the same issue

Comment: No you don't. As I say, there is no such thing as generics.NameView, so the only thing this code would do is raise AttributeError. You are not actually running this code.

Comment: if you want to use class-based views you should create method request methods in there.
Suggest you to read this:
[Django class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `generic.View` Instead of `generic.NameView`, like this

```
from django.views import generic

class NameView(generic.View)
      # you code ...
```